# Parse JSON using JSON Object

Tags: java, json

MY JSON response body from a service as follows

```
    {
    "Employee": {
        "Name": "Demo",
        "applied": true
                }
   }
```

I want to parse using JSON Object in Java.
i did like this

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(responseBody));
//responbosy is a JSONObject type 
obj.getString("Employee[0].name");
```

Please suggest how to do that

Comment: And what is wrong ??

Comment: It's not giving result throwing Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Employee` is not an array, only `JSONObject`
So you have do something like that:

```
obj.getJSONObject("Employee").getString("Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

I Think you want to have the name, yes?

Anyway, you can access it by using:

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(responseBody));
 JSONObject employee = new JSONObject(obj.getJSONObject("Employee"));

 employee.getString("Name"); 
 employee.getBoolean("applied");
```

Reason for this is:

Everything between

```
 {}
```

is an JSONObject. Everything between

```
[]
```

means it's an JSONArray.

In your String

```
     {
"Employee": {
    "Name": "Demo",
    "applied": true
            }
  }
```

You've an JSONObject because of starting with {}. Within this JSONObject you have an Propertie called "Employee" which has another JSONObject nested.

**Be Carefull:** applied is from type boolean, since it's true/false without "". If there's a number you should get it using getInteger(). if it's a boolean you can get it using getBoolean() and elsehow you should get it using getString().

you can see all available Datatypes at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON